# Why is MDI parent occasionally not minimizing?

Tags: vb.net, mdi, showdialog

I have a MDI parent that opens another form like this:

```
Dim frm As New Form1
frm.ShowDialog(Me)
```

That form has a button that, when clicked, does this:

```
CreateObject("Shell.Application").ToggleDesktop()
```

The button operates as expected (showing the desktop) most of the time but **occasionally** does not minimize the MDI parent.  All the other windows, including the form above get minimized every time.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the order in which the windows on the desktop get minimized.  Which is probably random.  Avoid using a dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to allow a form shown with `ShowDialog` I changed the angle from which I'm approaching.  I'll show the form with `Show` and assign the `MdiParent` and just fake the modality of the form instead.  The fake modal will disable all other parts of the MDI parent except the system buttons in the title bar.  If the user attempts to close the MDI parent, the "modal" window will beep once and blink the title bar a bit.